# Neo4j, There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: neo4j, disk, recover

In our application which is using neo4j-1.8.2 we have so called synchronization process. This process reads some data from SQL Server db, processes it in some way and makes appropriate changes to the graph database. In the case if we have disk space outage (those disk where we have neo4j database located), neo4j server stops working (it is still running stops answering the queries). In neo4j web admin I have the following response for each cypher query- "Failed to get current transaction.". In the log file I see:
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk

My question is: when I clean some content from disk and around 10GB of free space appeared, does it mean that neo4j server will start working (answering to queries) again automatically OR do I need to restart it?

I see that it is not working after cleaning some content, I have to restart it, then it starts working again? I want to know if this is expected or can I do something to avoid restarting neo4j server?

Thanks in advance,
Denys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to restart Neo4j when running out of disc. Best practice is to setup some monitoring system giving you alert if free disc space goes below a certain capacity.